# Regex: Finding specific word, excluding ones surrounded with a special char/tag

Tags: regex

I want to find a specific word in a text, but not the ones that surrounded with a special char, or tag, etc.

For example:

`This word should be find, but [this word] shouldn't.`

Is it possible to do this with Regular Expression? Or I should think about writing a special parser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
(^|[^\[])[Tt]his word($|[^$\]])
```

`(^|[^\[])` -> line start or everything except an opening square bracket

`[Tt]his word` -> make the first letter case insensitive

`($|[^\]])` -> line end or everything except an closing square bracket